# How to make image so that when clicked on, opens larger image (same image) on same page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, hyperlink

I've seen this done before on art sites, but usually the thumbnail image leads to a new page. I need the image to lead to a larger image, centered, on the same page. Here is a screenshot of the page so you'll see what I mean:https://i.stack.imgur.com/waZci.jpg  I would imagine that there's a fairly simple solution for this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

nav {width:100%;display:block;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;
padding:0;text-align:center;background-color:#222419}
nav li {display:inline-block;background-color:#222419;}
nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding: 0 30px; font-size:18px;
   font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:#222419;}
nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}

a{float:left;
  margin-right:58px;
  margin-left:58px;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;}

.head {width:100%}
.logo {display:inline-block;padding:10px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}
-->
</style> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>DrawYourPets.com</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<nav> 

<div style="text-align:center">
<title="DrawYourPetsBanner">
<img src="DrawYourPetsBanner2.jpg" border="0" alt="DrawYourPetsBanner2">
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="drawyourpets2.html"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="drawings.html"><strong>DRAWINGS<strong></a></li>
<li><a href="store.html"><strong>STORE</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>

</header>

<section>
<aside>
</aside>

<article>
<br>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center" class="head">
<div class="logo">
<figure>
<img src="Wesson.jpg" height="300px" weight="300px" alt="Wesson"/>
<figcaption>Wesson, 8.5'' x 11''</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<div class="logo">
<figure>
<img src="Stanley.jpg" height="300px" weight="300px" alt="Stanley"/>
<figcaption>Stanley, 13'' x 15''</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

<div class="logo">
<figure>
<img src="Archibald.jpg" height="300px" weight="300px" alt="Archibald"/>
<figcaption>Archibald, 13'' x 15''</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<br>
<div class="logo">
<figure>
<img src="Maggie.jpg" height="250px" weight="250px" alt="Maggie"/>
<figcaption>Maggie, 16'' x 13''</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>

</div>

</article>

</section>

<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See lightbox. There is a way how to do yourself, but for you lightbox is the right way.

Comment: Are you looking for an effect like this one but connected to the click of the mouse ? http://jsfiddle.net/rutevLfk/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p6yk2dm/)

```
<a href="#large"><img src=" "></a>

<img id="large" src=" " >
```

Comment: nb. the click doesnt `lead to a larger image, centered, on the same page` as the OP asked for...

Comment: @SW4 It seems to work fine for me, as soon as it is clicked the page will scroll down to the part where the image with id large is situated

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use onhover mouse event to present an enlarge shape of your image.

Comment: Needs to happen with a click, not hover